# Is there any way to verify that I have successfully frozen certain variables/parameters in my Tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I attempted to freeze some of the variables by only passing the variables that I would like to fine-tune on via the

```
 tf.train.AdamOptimizer.compute_gradients(var_list=[])
```

approach.

But when I proceeded with fine-tuning my model, the loss is going up and the accuracy is going down so I am having doubt that I have successfully frozen the initial few layers.

Any way to check if I'm freezing variables properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)`.

Comment: The variables I wanted to freeze are still there from tf.get_collection(). Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: Assuming your hidden layers have `scope = 'hidden**layer number**'`, try `train_us = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope = 'hidden[**layer numbers**]|outputs'` followed by `optimize_us = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list = train_us`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. And is there any chance I can check & validate that some layers are indeed frozen (for example would Tensorboard show the frozen vs trainable parts)?

Comment: `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` returns the trainable layers. If a layer is listed, it is trainable; if it is not listed, it is frozen.